# How do you perform soft delete with @EmbeddedId in Hibernate Java?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I cannot perform a soft delete with an @EmbeddedId?
The sql within the @SQLDelete is not being executed.

I have tried to hardcode value of the two id's to make up the embedded id.

I can get soft delete implementation work on entities with just @Id and not 
@EmbeddedId

When I run test with delete for entities with just @Id, I can see the sql being executed on the console but not with @EmbeddedId.

I think it just bypasses the @SQLDelete and uses the default delete sql from hibernate.
I'm expecting the sql within the @SQLDelete being executed.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "serviceEmployeeIdentity", callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "service_employee")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE service_employee " +
    "SET deleted = true " +
    "WHERE service_employee.service_id = ?1 " +
    "AND service_employee.employee_b_number = ?2")
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
public class ServiceEmployee extends Auditable implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ServiceEmployeeIdentity serviceEmployeeIdentity;

    @Column(name = "critical")
    private Boolean critical;

    @Column(name = "critical_rationale")
    private String criticalRationale;
}

@Repository
public interface ServiceEmployeeRepository extends 
JpaRepository<ServiceEmployee, ServiceEmployeeIdentity> {}

// test
ServiceEmployee serviceEmployee = ServiceEmployeeBuilder.aServiceEmployee();
serviceEmployeeService.deleteById(
    serviceEmployee.getServiceEmployeeIdentity());
```

Note: 
serviceEmployee has embeddedId set
serviceEmployeeService just calls the repository class

Answer (score 1):

This would work just like it does if it were a single valued `@Id` annotated column.  You simply need to specify multiple columns in the order of how they're represented in the embedded class, so use this in your `@SQLDelete`:

```
UPDATE service_employee
   SET deleted = true
 WHERE service_id = ?
   AND employee_b_number = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have tried just using service_id and employee_b_number instead of adding the service_employee. infront of it.  The problem still stands.

Comment: However I tried to create a custom "@Query" with native sql in the repository class. 
The query got executed but I was getting a "toString" exception.  

I have then added "@ToString" annotation and exclued the serviceEmployeeIdentity on the ServiceEmployee class and also added entityManager.flush in the test.

I was able to see the sql in the "@SQLDelete" got executed and the deleted flag got updated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried and worked for me but the order is alphabetically of the columns of embeddedId

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE (table_name) SET DELETED=true WHERE event_id = ? and payment_id=?")
```

If i use

```
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE (table_name) SET DELETED=true WHERE payment_id = ? and event_id=?")
```

it will not work and not update the register needed.